# Sending <script> tags in ajax content

Tags: javascript, dom, .net-security

I'm working on porting this lab: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Attacks_XSS/XSS.pdf

For a project. First, however, I have to be able to complete it myself. I'm trying to work out the self-propogating worm, and having some difficulties. How can I send a script tag through the content? If I try:

> ```
> var wormCode = getElementById("worm");
> var escapedWorm = escape(wormCode.innerHTML);
> content="topicTitle=testprop&postText=<script>"+escapedWorm+"</script>&forum=3&action=ptopic";
> Ajax.send(content);
> ```

The  tag breaks out of the larger javascript this sits in. I've also tried splitting it up as :

```
...+"</scr"+"ipt>&...
```

but this did not work.

Any tips?

edit: updated with my more recent (and I hope, accurate) attempts.

Comment: Thanks for being an ass. My assignment isn't to do this lab, it is to port it to our lab environment for next years class. The class didn't actually teach me how to do this.

Comment: @lbu `I'm working on porting this lab:` where does it say that its homework?

Comment: **Laboratory for Computer Security Education**
"You need to submit a detailed lab report to describe what you have done and what you have observed.
Please provide details using LiveHTTPHeaders, Wireshark, and/or screenshots. You also need to
provide explanation to the observations that are interesting or surprising."

Comment: Ibu, read the whole post before you dismiss it. I stated in literally the first sentence I was porting this lab for future classes.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right, the attempt you have listed, breaking it into two concatenated strings, should work.  Are you saying it still sees that as a closing script tag?

Comment: No, it is not seeing it as a closing script tag. However, it is in some way breaking what I intend to do, no new post is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var wormCode = getElementById("worm");
var escapedWorm = escape("<" + "script>" + wormCode.innerHTML + "</" + "script>");
content="topicTitle=testprop&forum=3&action=ptopic&postText="+escapedWorm;
Ajax.send(content);
```

You aren't escaping the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up the the end script tag into two different parts ended up working after all. I think that the issues I was having with it were browser-specific.